ConTeXt: Escape percent sign in \type command inside a tabulate
I'm quite new to ConTeXt and am using \type{...} inside a cell of a tabulate table. I would like to print a % percent sign, but cannot manage to do so. Using the plain percent sign causes error which I understand. I tried to escape the sign with a backslash and by using \letterpercent. None works. In both cases I get the literal output, i.e. \% or \letterpercent.
So not escaping causes an error, but all options of escaping I could find produce the wrong (i.e. literal) output. I feel lost and any hint would be appreciated.

You can put the content into a buffer
\startTEXpage[offset=1DK]

\type{code % comment}

\typ{code % comment}

\startbuffer[one]
  code % comment
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[two]
  \typ{code % comment}
\stopbuffer

\startbuffer[three]
  \type{code % comment}
\stopbuffer

\typeinlinebuffer

\starttabulate[|l|]
%   \NC \type{code % comment} \NC \NR % Fails
%   \NC \typ{code % comment}  \NC \NR % Fails
  \NC \typeinlinebuffer[one] \NC \NR
  \NC \inlinebuffer[two]     \NC \NR
  \NC \inlinebuffer[three]   \NC \NR
\stoptabulate

\stopTEXpage


You see that with \typ you do not get mono space.
PS Next time it is good if you give a small example sample. Now I had to guess that the above is what you are trying to do. Maybe I got you right, maybe not.

You can't use \type{%} in a taulate without a few workarounds because the environments reads the content of the whole environment before it builds a table which clashes with the way how \type works. As a result of this mechanism the % of the \type argument works as a normal comment for the input line and you get an error message.
With the \letterpercent command you can output a % in the style of the current font, to get a monospace % use the \mono command.
Another method to use % as argument for \type add a asciimode environment around the tabulate environment which changes the meaning % to prevent it from working as the comment character.
\starttext

\startasciimode
\starttabulate[|||]
\NC \tex{letterpercent}              \EQ \letterpercent        \NC\NR
\NC \tex{mono} + \tex{letterpercent} \EQ \mono{\letterpercent} \NC\NR
\NC \tex{type} + \letterpercent      \EQ \type{%}              \NC\NR
\stoptabulate
\stopasciimode

\stoptext


